# verify that xml node has a child node with a given value tsql

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, t-sql

I have the following tables

```
A (ID, relatedID, typeId )
B (ID, leftID, leftTypeId)
```

I want to join the two tables like this

```
select * from A
inner join B on A.TypeId=B.LeftTypeId and {condition}
```

where **condition** should verify id the **leftID** would match a value from **relatedID**, where relatedId is a xml column. Eg. relatedID=`<Id>1</Id>`

Is there a optimal way to do this?

**UPDATE**
`relatedID` can contain several Ids. Eg Eg. `relatedID=<Id>1</Id><Id>2</Id>`

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` to get the xml value for each row in `A`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
... and A.relatedID.value('(/Id[1]/text())[1]', 'int') = B.leftID
```

or

```
... and A.relatedID.exist('(/Id[1]/text())[1] = sql:column("B.leftID")') = 1
```

Though `exist` is recommended over `value` for predicates, depending on whether the `XML` column is xml-indexed or not and what type of indexes it has, one of the two above may perform better.

**upd.** for the case when relatedID can contain set of Ids you may try

```
select ...
from A
    cross apply A.relatedID.nodes('/Id') r(id)
    inner join B on A.TypeId=B.LeftTypeId
        and r.id.value('text()[1]', 'int') = B.leftID
```

or

```
select ...
from A
    cross apply A.relatedID.nodes('/Id') r(id)
    inner join B on A.TypeId=B.LeftTypeId
        and r.id.exist('text()[1]=sql:column("B.leftID")') = 1
```

or even

```
select ...
from A
    inner join B on A.TypeId=B.LeftTypeId
        and A.relatedID.exist('/Id[text()[1]=sql:column("B.leftID")]') = 1
```

Comment: The code from what I understand works when the content of relatedId only contains one Id. But what if there are several and I want to verify if the B.leftID is contained in the sequence given by the the relatedId xml?